# Run batch file using windows shortcut?

Tags: windows, batch-file, keyboard-shortcuts

I make pretty repetitive file structures for my job and I have a batch file setup that automates the process for me.

I was wondering if there was a way to link the batch file to a shortcut (like win+N or something) so that I can run the file from anywhere instead of having to copy paste the batch file into whatever directory i'm using every time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example to show you how you can create a shortcut on your desktop for your batch file with icon and set a Hot key like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

---

```bat
@echo off & Title Playing Some Radios Stations
REM First we create a Shortcut with a Hotkey "CTRL+R" by calling this sub like this way : 
REM CreateShortcut <ApplicationPath> <ShortcutName> <Icon> <HotKey>
Call :CreateShortcut "%~f0" "Radios Stations" "%Windir%\System32\SHELL32.dll,138" "CTRL+R"
:menuLOOP
Title Playing Some Radios Stations
Color 9E & Mode 80,18
::===========================================================================
echo(
echo(
echo(       ***************************** Menu ******************************
echo(
@for /f "tokens=2* delims=_ " %%A in ('"findstr /b /c:":menu_" "%~f0""') do (
echo(                 %%A  %%B)
echo(
echo(       *****************************************************************
echo( &Set /p Selection=Make a Selection or hit ENTER to quit: ||Goto :EOF
echo( & Call:menu_[%Selection%]
GOTO:menuLOOP
::===========================================================================
:menu_[1] Play DJ Buzz Radio Station
Call :StopMusic
Set "Music_URL=https://stream.initialradio.fr:8443/djbuzz-192k.mp3"
Call :Play "%Music_URL%" "Playing DJ Buzz Radio Station"
Goto:menuLoop
::---------------------------------------------------------------------------
:menu_[2] Play RetroDance Radio Station
Call :StopMusic
Set "Music_URL=http://retro.dancewave.online/retrodance.mp3"
Call :Play "%Music_URL%" "Play RetroDance Radio Station"
Goto:menuLoop
::---------------------------------------------------------------------------
:menu_[3] Play Radio Mosaique DJ Station
Call :StopMusic
Set "Music_URL=http://radio.mosaiquefm.net:8000/mosadj"
Call :Play "%Music_URL%" "Playing Radio Mosaique DJ Station"
Goto:menuLoop
::---------------------------------------------------------------------------
:menu_[4] Play Radio Mosaique GOLD Station
Call :StopMusic
Set "Music_URL=http://radio.mosaiquefm.net:8000/mosagold"
Call :Play "%Music_URL%" "Playing Radio Mosaique GOLD Station"
Goto:menuLoop
::---------------------------------------------------------------------------
:menu_[5] Play Radio 100% HIT JFM Station
Call :StopMusic
Set "Music_URL=http://streaming2.toutech.net:8000/jfmweb4"
Call :Play "%Music_URL%" "Playing Radio 100%%%% HIT JFM Station"
Goto:menuLoop
::---------------------------------------------------------------------------
:menu_[6] Play Radio 100% GOLD JFM Station 
Call :StopMusic
Set "Music_URL=http://streaming2.toutech.net:8000/jfmweb2"
Call :Play "%Music_URL%" "Playing Radio 100%%%% GOLD JFM Station"
Goto:menuLoop
::---------------------------------------------------------------------------
:menu_[7] Play Radio 100% CLUBBING JFM Station
Call :StopMusic
Set "Music_URL=http://streaming2.toutech.net:8000/jfmweb3"
Call :Play "%Music_URL%" "Playing Radio 100%%%% CLUBBING JFM Station"
Goto:menuLoop
::---------------------------------------------------------------------------
:menu_[8] Play Generation Dance Radio
Call :StopMusic
Set "Music_URL=http://generationdance.lu:8010/hd"
Call :Play "%Music_URL%" "Playing Generation Dance Radio"
Goto:menuLoop
::---------------------------------------------------------------------------
:menu_[9] Stop Stremaing Radio station
Call :StopMusic
Goto:menuLoop
::---------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Play <URL> <Title>
(
    echo Play "%~1"
    echo Sub Play(URL^)
    echo    Dim Sound
    echo    Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX"^)
    echo    Sound.URL = URL
    echo    Sound.settings.volume = 100
    echo    Sound.Controls.play
    echo    While Sound.playState ^<^> 1
    echo        wscript.sleep 100
    echo    Wend
    echo End Sub
)>"%Temp%\PlayMusic.vbs"
start "%~2" /Min cscript.exe //nologo "%Temp%\PlayMusic.vbs"
exit /b
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:StopMusic
Taskkill /IM "cscript.exe" /F >Nul 2>&1
Exit /B
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:CreateShortcut <ApplicationPath> <ShortcutName> <Icon> <HotKey>
(
    echo Call Shortcut("%~1","%~2","%~3","%~4"^)
    echo Sub Shortcut(ApplicationPath,Name,Icon,HotKey^)
    echo    Dim objShell,DesktopPath,objShortCut,MyTab
    echo    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
    echo    MyTab = Split^(ApplicationPath,"\"^)
    echo    If Name = "" Then
    echo        Name = MyTab(UBound^(MyTab^)^)
    echo    End if
    echo    DesktopPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop"^)
    echo    Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath ^& "\" ^& Name ^& ".lnk"^)
    echo    objShortCut.TargetPath = Chr(34^) ^& ApplicationPath ^& Chr^(34^)
    echo    ObjShortCut.IconLocation = Icon
    echo    ObjShortCut.WorkingDirectory = "%~dp0"
    echo    objShortCut.HotKey = Hotkey
    echo    objShortCut.Save
    echo End Sub
)>"%temp%\Shortcutme.vbs"
wscript "%temp%\Shortcutme.vbs" & Del "%temp%\Shortcutme.vbs"
Exit /b
::------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```